# Incorrect indentation in emacs python-mode

Tags: python, emacs

If I have an object with a property named `Class`, and I refer to that object in an if statement, emacs will misindent the `else:` line of the if statement.  The expected indentation and the indentation that emacs gives are as follows.

```
def func():
    if obj.Class:
        pass
    else:  # Correct indentation
        pass

def func():
    if obj.Class:
        pass
else:  # emacs indentation
    pass
```

I haven't been able to find any information on this issue before.  Is this a known issue, and if so, is there a solution to it?  I am using emacs 24.5.1.

Comment: Is `if` indentation in other cases correct?

Comment: There are various Python modes for emacs, and all of them come with their own indentation bugs.  What's the result of `C-h v py-version <RET>`?

Comment: @Alex.S In other cases, the if indentation is correct.  The indentation is incorrect only if `Class` (case-insensitive) is present in the if statement.  If I change it to `GetClass` or 'OtherProperty`, then the indentation is correct.

Comment: @SvenMarnach `C-h v py-version <RET>` shows `[no match]`.  This was done using the `-q` flag, so the only python version present should be the one that comes installed by default.

Comment: @EldritchCheese: OK, then you are not using the Python mode I happen to know about, which means I can't help you with this question. :)

Comment: This is a bug of python.el, please consider a bug report. py-version is provided by python-mode.el, as delivered by melpa. You may use both modes in parallel - however last loaded takes the key-map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried this. Indeed, this is a bug, it appears python-mode thinks keywords are case-insensitive:

```
def func():
    if obj.Class:
        pass
else:
    pass

def func():
    if obj.Klass:
        pass
    else:
        pass

def func():
    if obj.If:
        pass
else:
    pass
```

That means you have to live with it. You can of course work around this by using the more common name, `cls` instead of `Class`.

Comment: Alas.  I was kind of expecting that, but hoping that I had done something silly.  Unfortunately, it is a separate library not under my control that has the `Class` method, otherwise I would change it to `cls`.